# DAO pattern multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, dao

I work on an multithreading Java application, it is a web server that provide REST services, about 1000 requests per second. I have a relational database, and I use hibernate for accessing it. The database has about 300-400 request per second. I am wondering if DAO pattern is correct, from the multi threading perspective.

So, there is one BaseModel class that looks like this:

```
public class BaseModelDAO 
{

    protected Session session;


    protected final void commit() {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }


    protected final void openSession() {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

}
```

Then I have a DAO class for every table from database:

```
public class ClientDAOHibernate extends BaseModelDAO implements ClientDAO 
{

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public synchronized void addClient(Client client) throws Exception {
        try {
            openSession();
            session.save(client);
            commit();
            log.debug("client successfully added into database");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error adding new client into database");
            throw new Exception("couldn't add client into database");
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Client getClient(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        Client client = null;
        try {
            openSession();
            client = (Client) session.createCriteria(Client.class).createAlias("user", "UserAlias").add(Restrictions.eq("UserAlias.username", username)).add(Restrictions.eq("UserAlias.password", password)).uniqueResult();
            commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error updating user into database");
            throw new DBUsersGetUserException();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. It is ok to open and close the session for every access to db, taking in consideration the number of concurrent requests?
2. Now DAO classes are accessed directly from application business logic. Should be used a DAO manager insted? If yes, what should be a good design to implement it?

Comment: I'm probably not an expert enough to fully answer your question, but I can say you will need to be careful about closing the session too early. If you attempt to use any Hibernate objects after the session is closed it will break any lazy loading of other entities or data. I think the best approach would be to have a service layer to hold the business logic and a hibernate session/transaction wrapped around each method in the service layer. If you are using a framework like Spring (integrated with Hibernate) it's really to get this working by putting `@Transactional` on the service methods.

Comment: @Michael what do you mean by "using Hibernate objects after the session is closed"? after the session is close, no other hibernate objects are used. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I am referring to your entities that you load from Hibernate (i.e. the objects that map to your database tables) not just the ones provided by Hibernate as a part of the framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, your implementation is not a good one:

- transactions should be around business logic, not around data access logic: if you want to transfer money from one account to another, you can't have a transaction for the debit operation, and another transaction for the credit operation. The transaction must cover the whole use-case.
- by synchronizing every method of the DAO, you forbid two requests to get a client at the same time. You should not have a session field in your DAO. The session should be a local variable of each method. By doing this, your DAO would become stateless, and thus inherently thread-safe, without any need for synchronization
- As Michael says in his comment, using programmatic transactions makes the code verbose, complex, and not focused to the business use-case. Use EJBs or Spring to enjoy declarative transaction management and exception handling.

Comment: +1, but not EJBs please!! I'm still scarred from ejb 1.1. It's a wound that will never heal :)

Comment: if I use a session in every method, I get the next message from server: "Too many connections", even if I close the connection every time the job is done.

Comment: if you get this message, you probably didn't configure your database and/or connection pool correctly.